# R8 FullMode Debug throwing Transition XXX is not a valid framework Transition or AndroidX Transition

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

With **android.enableR8.fullMode=true** and **minifyEnabled true** on **Debug** builds we are seeing the following runtime error (multiple devices and the emulator):

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transition
> Slide@b15f5f5: dur(400)  for fragment MyFragment is not a valid
> framework Transition or AndroidX Transition

On a **Release** build it doesn't happen (with R8 FullMode on)

If I turn R8 FullMode off we don't see the error on the Debug build

```
import androidx.transition.TransitionInflater

abstract class MyBaseFragment : Fragment() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right)
  }
}
```

slide_right.xml:

```
<slide xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
  android:slideEdge="right" />
```

proguard-rules.pro (snippet):

```
-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
   <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
   public static <fields>;
}
```

Anyone have any clue why R8 FullMode would do this on debug builds?  Are there any additional proguard rules that might need to be added in this case?

Comment: This sounds like an issue which should be reported on the R8 iussue tracker. You can use https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788. If possible attach a reproduction to the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in R8.  https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/241478253

Workaround for the issue is to add a proguard rule for:

```
- keep class androidx.transition.FragmentTransitionSupport
```